# HTML5 canvas is resizing my image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, canvas

so I am trying to simply put an image as the full size of the canvas

I know my images height and width so i set the css accordingly:

```
#canvas{
    width:500px;
    height:322px;
}
```

then I used the tutorial from [here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-images/) for putting an image on the canvas.

because I use a canvas that is the size of the image, you would think this would work perfectly, **but it resizes the image**. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

## [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nDjJK/)

Comment: Well.. if you console.log(canvas.width).. you'll see that canvas is set to be 300px wide instead of the 500px that you set in css style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Css style defines the size of the canvas that is displayed.. So your canvas will appear to be 500px wide and 332px high. But doesn't really define the dimension within the canvas. So the canvas may only have some default pixel width and height. 
when you new an canvas. Say:

```
var canvas = document.createElment('canvas');
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 322;
```

Those width and height definition will define the actually canvas pixel size, and can be set differently from css.